# How to migrate to a specific part of a html page after a struts action forward?

Tags: struts-1

I am using Struts 1. I wonder how I can show a particular part of a html page after mapping.findForward("success"); is returned and a jsp is processed.

For example, I can use this url to show a part of html with id="contact" even if it is way below on a page.

http: //www.mycompany.com/generalInfo#contact

But how can I do it after a struts action forward?

Comment: There's nothing in the standard S1 config that will let you do this. The *easiest* thing to do would probably be to keep something representing the anchor in the DOM or as JS, and use any of the JS scrolling libs to check for it and scroll if needed.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks. I think this would do the trick document.getElementById('youridhere').scrollIntoView();